# Maintenance for a single speed bike

Tags: maintenance, preventative-maintenance

I love biking. And I also love maintaining my bikes. This is the first time I've gotten a single speed road bike, specifically [this one.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004GWP6CK)

My question is, for maintenance purposes, what should I look out for? I've considered getting a truing station, but I'm not too sure that's something I need to worry for a single speed road bike?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to maintain:

tyres, chain, brakes; less frequently, chain ring, freewheel (or sprocket); even less frequently, bottom bracket

Their beauty is their simplicity.

By all means get the kit to true your wheel, but that again is something that I'd lump in the "even less frequently" category.

Comment: My old bike need the front wheel to be trued maybe a month after I used it. It puzzled me how it got so bent out of shape like that in just the first month. Thankfully, after getting it trued (not by myself), it was fine.

Comment: For all of the places you said that should be maintained, is there any specific actions I should be taking to make sure it's being maintained properly?

Comment: Well, day-to-day care would really just involve keeping the tyres up and the chain clean & lubed. These steps will maximise the lifetime of drivetrain components, although of course everything will wear out eventually. I'm surprised you ended up having to true a wheel, it really isn't all that common, I suspect in your case it was never true i.e. put together poorly.

Comment: Its a Walmart level bike - it isn't surprising that the wheel has to be trued.

Comment: I agree.  It's common (particularly on lower end bikes/wheels) that the wheels need to be adjusted once (or several times) after riding for a little while.  As the wheel flexes and shifts, spokes loosen up.  You have to keep dialing them in until this process stops.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tools for other bikes the tools specific to SS are

1. freewheel remover
2. wrench for rear axle
   it is just standard size but if you going to put one in your bag they have carry wrenches
3. chain tool needs to be beefy enough for 1/8 (most are not)